# IIS Error HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

I have website setup in IIS manager, when I select to view Browse the website, I get the follwoing error: HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized  ...You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server.

I've confirmed that I have full admin rights on the remote computer; In addition, I added IIS_IUSRS and applied full control / admin rights. However, still, I get the related Error: HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized. I did notice that  the "Permissions" for myself all have checks: Full control ...etc that our dimmed, but for IIS_IUSRS, the checks are bold; so am not sure if that makes a difference.

If I could gets some guidance as to what I may be doing wrong or if there is something else I need to look into in resolving the error, any suggestions our welcomed.

Comment: Is it a webform application, i.e. has it default.aspx or index.aspx which was not set as a default page on the website? If default page is not set on IIS then it might be that when you call it without page (i.e. http://domainname) it cannot find page but directory browsing is disabled

Comment: IIS is not a console application but a Windows service, so you cannot use your previous experience in that simple way. Try to first provide more information of your IIS setup, such as what authentication method is used and who sees the 401.3 error page. The error page itself also includes hints on what's next to check.

Comment: @smirnov that should not trigger 401.3.